# Google Colaboratory integration with github

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, data-science, google-colaboratory

How do I import entire repository or a notebook from github to Google colab like I do in azure notebooks & IBM DS workbench

Answer (score 0):

Just doing a simple git clone will do:

```
!git clone githubrepohtml
%cd githubrepo_folder_name
```